# Changing value of a variable on OnClick Android

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons in my layout when user presses button 1 the value of 'number' should change to '2' and when the user presses button 2 the value of 'number' should change to '1'.But the value does not change. 
Here is my code :

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity{

public  int number ;

private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testing);

    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    test();
}

void test()
{

  if(number<1) {
    number = 1;
    }

        Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));


    if(number==1)
    {

         btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
          number=2;

             Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));


         }

    });

    }


     if(number==2)
    {
     btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             number=1;
             Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));

    }

    });

    }


    }
```

Log.e outputs

```
 E/number value :: 2
```

when I press btn1 but when i press btn2 nothing happens and only btn1 works

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
void test()
{

  if(number<1) { number = 1; }

  Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));

  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0)  {
       if(number == 1)
       {
         number=2;
         Log.e("Button 1 number value : ",String.valueOf(number));
       }
     }
  });

  btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0)  {
       if(number == 2)
       {
         number=1;
         Log.e("Button 2 number value : ",String.valueOf(number));
       }
     }
  });

}
```

Comment: This works!. But can you please explain why it does not work with an if condition?

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code doesn't gets called at all:

```
if(number==2)
    {
     btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             number=1;
             Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));

    }

    });
```

The reason is the condition `if(number==2)` because number is actually 1 so this block of code doesn't get called, so there is no click listener added to the `btn2`.

set the click listener in `onCreate` and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testing);

    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
          number=2;
             Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));
         }

    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             number=1;
             Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));
    }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public class test extends AppCompatActivity{

    public  int number ;

    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testing);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        test();


         btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
          if(number==1){
          number=2;
            }
             Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));

         }
    });


     btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(number==2){
             number=1;
          }
             Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));

    }

    });


}

    void test()
    {

      if(number<1) {
        number = 1;
        }

            Log.e("number value : ",String.valueOf(number));    

        }    

 }
```